# Создание виртуального устройства с помощью device-mapper подвешивает загрузку системы

Tags: linux, boot, device-mapper, udev, initramfs

Необходимо создать виртуальное устройство с помощью утилиты **device-mapper** во время загрузки системы.

Для этого я создаю свою копию **initramfs (initrd)** с помощью утилиты **mkinitcpio**. Указываю следующий конфигруационный файл:

```
MODULES="dm-mod basic_target"
BINARIES="dmsetup"
FILES="/etc/udev/rules.d/61-local.rules /lib/udev/create_virtual.sh"
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

**basic_target** - самописный модуль ядра, исходный код которого скопирован с небольшими изменениями из этой [статьи](http://techgmm.blogspot.ru/p/writing-your-own-device-mapper-target.html).

Содержимое файла **/etc/udev/rules.d/61-local.rules**:

```
KERNEL=="sd*",SUBSYSTEM=="block",ACTION=="add",ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="abe3b587-3a5f-47d6-8f66-2df758e70665",RUN+="/lib/udev/create_virtual.sh %k"
```

Содержимое **/lib/udev/create_virtual.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
dmsetup create root_part --table "0 32359055360 basic_target /dev/$1 0"
exit 0
```

Правила udev выполняются и скрипт запускается. Однако под конец выполнения конструктора device mapper target-а (его код изложен далее) загрузка зависает на некоторое время.

Вот код конструктора:

```
static int basic_target_ctr(struct dm_target *ti, unsigned int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct my_dm_target *mdt;
    unsigned long long start;

    printk(KERN_CRIT "\n >>in function basic_target_ctr \n");

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printk(KERN_CRIT "\n Invalid no of arguments.\n");
        ti->error = "Invalid argument count";
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    mdt = kmalloc(sizeof(struct my_dm_target), GFP_KERNEL);

    if (mdt == NULL)
    {
        printk(KERN_CRIT "\n Mdt is null\n");
        ti->error = "dm-basic_target: Cannot allocate linear context";
        return -ENOMEM;
    }       

    if (sscanf(argv[1], "%llu", &start) != 1)
    {
        ti->error = "dm-basic_target: Invalid device sector";
        goto bad;
    }

    mdt->start = (sector_t)start;

    if (dm_get_device(ti, argv[0], dm_table_get_mode(ti->table), &mdt->dev))
    {
        ti->error = "dm-basic_target: Device lookup failed";
        goto bad;
    }

    ti->private = mdt;

    printk(KERN_CRIT "\n>>out function basic_target_ctr \n");                       

    return 0;
bad:
    kfree(mdt);
    printk(KERN_CRIT "\n>>out function basic_target_ctr with errorrrrrrrrrr \n");           
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

Строка *">>out function basic_target_ctr"* выводится и дальше ничего не происходит.

При этом в уже загруженной системе скрипт, запущенный вручную, срабатывает успешно. **dmesg** говорит, что после завершения работы конструктора ещё выполняется два запроса на чтение (функция basic_target_map из статьи). Эти запросы не выполняются в момент загрузки системы.

На всякий случай, функция basic_target_map:

```
static int basic_target_map(struct dm_target *ti, struct bio *bio)
{
    struct my_dm_target *mdt = (struct my_dm_target *) ti->private;

    printk(KERN_CRIT "\n<<in function basic_target_map \n");

    bio->bi_bdev = mdt->dev->bdev;

    if((bio->bi_opf & WRITE) == WRITE)
        printk(KERN_CRIT "\n basic_target_map : bio is a write request.... \n");
    else
        printk(KERN_CRIT "\n basic_target_map : bio is a read request.... \n");

    submit_bio(bio);

    printk(KERN_CRIT "\n>>out function basic_target_map \n");

    return DM_MAPIO_SUBMITTED;
}
```

После около минутного ожидания загрузка системы проодолжается. При этом в системе не перестаёт "висеть" ещё один udev демон, который запускался на этапе загрузки.

Подскажите, какие ошибки присутствуют в этом алгоритме, и как их исправить!